# Как сделать чтобы функция возращала массив

Tags: c, массивы, функции

```
unsigned char matr_words[N][3][81];
char word[N], words[N], ABC_words[N];
char words_v2[N];

int *find(char* word, char* words, int alllenn, int wdw) //функция которая проверяет если повтор?
{
    char* istr;
    istr = strstr(words, word);
    int t = istr - words;
    if (istr == NULL) return words; //если повтора нет то возращает начальный массив
    else { //если повтор обнаружен "удалет" слово путем перезаписывания в другой массив
        for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
            words_v2[i] = words[i];
        }
        for (int i = t; i < (alllenn - wdw + 1); i++) words_v2[i] = words[i + wdw];
        int new_len_words = alllenn - wdw;
        return words_v2; // теперь возращает новый массив
    }
}
```

если сама функция работает правильно, но как сделать чтобы когда вызываю ее она возращала нужный мне массив?

Comment: массивы возвращаются и принимаются только по указателям. `int * find(char* word, ..` `return words;` и `return wors_v2;`

Comment: спасибо сейчас попробую

Comment: @AlexGlebe я исправила можете посмотреть правильно ли я вас поняла?

Comment: нормально, мне неизвестно, как вы с этими массивами дальше будете работать. Вы должны понимать, что массивы в единственном экземпляре, и вы передаёте всего-лишь указатели на глобальные  массивы.